# Finding intersection with newton's method for $\cos(x) = 2x$

Tags: calculus

I have spent the last 30 minutes to figure out what I am doing wrong. Maybe someone can spot the error:

I have to find the intersection using newton's method for $$\cos(x) = 2x$$

Newton's Method says $$X_{n+1}=X_n-\frac{f(X_n)}{f'(X_n)}$$

So I did the following steps:

$$\cos(x) = 2x$$
$$0 = 2x - \cos(x)$$

If I graph 2x and cos(x) the intersection should be somewhere between 0 and 1. So I chose 0.5 for $X_n$

$$X_1 = 0.5 - \frac{2 \cdot0.5-\cos(0.5)}{2+\sin(0.5)}= 0.4999810$$ as per calculator.

The result though should be close to $0.4506$

Where am I missing the step?

Comment: Did you use radians or degrees?

Comment: It says D so I guess it is degrees

Comment: The result is using radians

Comment: damn.. now the result is correct.. just waisted 30 minutes of my life :D

Comment: Take it easy, you learned that it is important to distinguish between angles and dimensionless numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem has been diagnosed appropriately in the comments, here is a summary:

This questions requires that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ be taken with $x$ in radians rather than degrees.  Usually, any formula requiring the differentiation of a trigonometric function requires that you take the arguments of said functions to be in radians.

Comment: There is no reason that the argument of the sine or cosine functions need be in radians in order to take the derivatives of those functions, but the results are different. If $\theta$ represents the degree measure of an angle, for example, then $\frac{d}{d\theta} \sin(\theta) = \pi\cos(\theta)/180$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure indeed.  What I mean though is that in most contexts where $\sin$ shows up in an expression that is differentiated, they are referring to the $\sin$ of an angle in radians.

Comment: Then I agree with what you meant, just not what you wrote. :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following steps:

$$f(X_n)=\cos(x)-2x; \, f'(X_n)=-\sin(x)-2$$

for using Newton's Method by successive iterations:

$$X_{n+1}=X_n-\frac{f(X_n)}{f'(X_n)},$$

sticking to angles in radian measure  for speed and  convenience.

Answer (score 0):

So, if, finding an answer in any periodic function requires only looking at one revolution or cycle, could you just simplify the range (either radians or degrees), and look between 0-2pi radians?

Then, regardless of what you plug in for 'r' (or what you've called x) in both equations, gives cos(r) = 2r.

Now, we know that the result of 0 doesn't work, and we would generally look in the space between 1 and another integer, up to (but perhaps not including 2pi).  So then between 1 and roughly 6, are there any whole numbers that would make cos(r) = 2r?

And so, what I am showing you is a simple way that you can apply Newton's method for any intersection, zero happening to be an arbitrary non-existent number intersection.  And the non-existence of 0 as a value, but more as a reference point, is why you CAN do newton's method.  From one moment to the next, if you transition from a value less than what you're looking for to more than what you're looking for, you can bisect the difference between the two moments to find the inflection point that is whatever value you're searching for.  In this case, your value happens to be: where does cos(r) = 2r.  I hope that the reduction of the domain using the definition of periodic functions helps illuminate your search.

I am also trying to intuit this problem, and may have completely misunderstood your effort to, so there's that.

Comment: And now that I think about it, technically, you'd could halve my original assumption regarding the domain, and limit it to 0-pi, as periodic function of cos repeats every pi radians. . . ugh.